# Android application with ActionBar NullPointerException with non default locale

Tags: android, localization, tabs, android-actionbar, locale

I created pretty basic Android application with ActionBar and 2 tabs. It worked OK. Then I added locale resource directory `res/values-de` and inside it `strings.xml` with strings translated in German language. I changed language on my Nexus7 to German and application is unable to start after deployment. I got the same problem on emulator.

Please can you help me make this application running with some non default locale on my mobile device? In my case German...

Following error is reported.

```
02-07 15:32:41.314: W/dalvikvm(16682): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d82930)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabactionbar/com.example.tabactionbar.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682): **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at com.example.tabactionbar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)**
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-07 15:32:41.324: E/AndroidRuntime(16682):    ... 11 more
02-07 15:32:41.334: W/ActivityManager(492):   Force finishing activity com.example.tabactionbar/.MainActivity
02-07 15:32:41.434: D/dalvikvm(492): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 546K, 19% free 15994K/19568K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
02-07 15:32:41.574: D/libgps(492): proxy_gps_nmea_cb()
```

**MainActivity code without TabListener:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label1);
    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> tl = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this,
            label1, Tab1Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(tl);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.label2);
    tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label2);
    TabListener<Tab2Fragment> tl2 = new TabListener<Tab2Fragment>(this,
            label2, Tab2Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(tl2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);          
}
```

Reported line 20 in error is 
    **actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);**

**strings.xml with German** text is

```
<string name="app_name">TabActionBar</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
<string name="label1">Eins</string>
<string name="label2">Zwei</string>
<string name="body1">Erste</string>
<string name="body2">Zweite</string>
```

Please can you help me make this application running with some non default locale on my mobile device? In my case German...

Comment: Did you test if your actionBar object is not null ?

Comment: It is working with the default strings file?

Comment: If my device has set English which is default locale for my application then actionBar variable is not null after statement ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(). For English language application has strings in res/values directory and it works OK. But if I switch my device to German language then actionBar variable is null after statement ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(). So for default string file it works ok but simple switch of my device to German language causes that actionBar has null value which results to NullPointerException. For German language strings.xml is in res/values-de.

Comment: I allready answered this question in a other thread, check here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/33079919/2612536

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this discussion:
[Action Bar - Menu Button - Missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320775/action-bar-menu-button-missing)

By any chance, do you also have the ***styles.xml*** file inside the ***values-de*** folder? This could cause problems with the ActionBar becoming NULL.

Comment: Yes in directory res/values-de I have a file styles.xml and it has following content <resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

</resources>

Comment: I deleted styles.xml from res/values-de directory and it works OK. Thank you Alex Mocanu ! :-)