# Change app language in android 5.0 doesn't work

Tags: android, locale, android-context

I'm using this code below to change my app language on button click (changing from french to english for example), it's works fine on android 4.0 + but on 5.0 it doesn't.

```
Locale localeEn = new Locale("en_US");
Locale.setDefault(localeEn);
Configuration configEn = new Configuration();
configEn.locale = localeEn;
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configEn, null);
this.recreate();
```

Any clues why please?

edit : 
this is my manifest ( with android:configChanges )

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|locale"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: You need to use your activity context and not your application context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change app language programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Per-app language feature was just added to the latest Android API 33, that is still on Developer preview. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71151685/5038317

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to change from this:

```
Locale localeEn = new Locale("en_US");
Locale.setDefault(localeEn);
```

to this

```
String language = "en";
String country = "US";
Locale locale = new Locale(language , country);
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution, that i got from [Udhay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12954037/2612536), works when user changes the language in actionbar and app "refreshes" with selected language. I am using android 6.0.

There is no need to add locale to androidManifest.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    Locale locale = null;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_en:
            locale = new Locale("en_US");
            Toast.makeText(this, "English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.action_is:
            locale = new Locale("is", "IS");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Íslanska", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }

    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `android:configChanges="locale"` in `AndroidManifest.xml`? I think the problem is in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

You can see example change locale on [my github repository.](https://github.com/mlevytskiy/irregular_verbs/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/template/mlevytskiy/App.java)

Answer (score 1):

My solution was changing the locale before activity's

```
setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
```