# Action Bar and menu options are missing - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I am practicing a tutorial. App was working fine before I implemented list view. Now the action bar and the menu options disappeared. Can someone help me to identify the issue.Below is the required code (please advise if more info is required).

**activity_home.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**styles.xml**

```
 <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

**manifest.xml**

```
 <application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        >

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".UpdateStatusActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_update_status"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Here is the solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320775/action-bar-menu-button-missing

Comment: Here is the **solution** - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320775/action-bar-menu-button-missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file to

```
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest you have mentioned AppTheme as the theme of the application but for every activity you have mentioned theme as AppTheme.NoActionBar 
For HomeActivity you need to use the AppTheme instead of NoActionBar theme
Just remove

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

From your activity tag in the manifest for HomeActiviy

Answer (score 0):

you used in manifest.xml file `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"`
don't write android:theme line if you can't change the theme